# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rotaryio'

Tags: circuitpython

I recently went through the process of installing Adafruit-Blinka on a Raspberry Pi. The intent was to gain access to the 'rotaryio' module included with Circuitpython. After I went through the installation steps, ran a test script to confirm the installation was successful;
'import board', 'import digitalio', etc.. However when I run a script to "import rotaryio", I get the 'no module named rotaryio' error message. According to the Adafruit documentation 'rotaryio' is included in the installation.

Any suggestions on how to correct this error would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Circuit Python runs on *Pico* - not the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: NOTE the Adafruit-Blinka "instructions" are 5 years old and won't run on Bookworm.

Comment: Regarding Circuit Python , I can successfully run Circuit Python modules for MCP4275 and the PCA9685 boards. I was also able to run the Blinka Test python script after installing it. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 0):

Per this [page](https://learn.adafruit.com/circuitpython-on-raspberrypi-linux/faq-troubleshooting)  "Rotary encoders (rotaryio) is handled by interrupts on microcontrollers, and is not supported on SBCs at this time". Also, if you look [here](https://docs.circuitpython.org/en/latest/shared-bindings/rotaryio/index.html)   rotaryio is not listed as available on the Raspberry Pi, however, the Pi Pico is.

Comment: In addition "It was last updated on Jun 30, 2018" - it certainly doesn't seem to know  about python 3.11